# vb.net arcobjects determine 'create features' on which layer

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, editing, features, vb.net

When I create new feature in editing session, I need to determine the new created feature is in which layer because after that have further more action on the layer. I wonder can this be done in vb.net arcobjects?

I am using vs2012 and arcmap 10.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need to respond to the [IEditEvents.OnCreateFeature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000p6000000)  which returns an object of type IFeature which has a property [Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Class_Property/00250000062r000000/) which will give you the feature class it belongs to.

After you have the feature class belonging to the new feature you can iterate through your editable layers (using [IEditLayers.IsEdtiable](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IsEditable_Method/0020000000qn000000/)) and see if the (ILayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass matches - this will tell you what layer it is.

Comment: Thanks Michael, looks little complicated. Would trouble you if I still get problem in it.

Comment: It is (sort of) complicated, event programming is a little bit daunting at the start. You are using VB.net which is a little easier than C# when it comes to events. There's a little too much code to post in an answer - if you have a problem with one of the concepts you will get more detailed help with it like : How do I wire and respond to IEditEvents.OnCreateFeature in ArcGis? There are a few sample scripts around to show you how on the Esri help but they can be a little confusing.